# python pillow increases gif file size x10

Tags: python-imaging-library, exiftool

I want to change the duration of an animated gif.

Using Python Pil I extract the frames and then create a new gif with a different duration.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import os

def extractFrames(inGif):
    frame = Image.open(inGif)
    frames = []
    nframes = 0
    while frame:
        frames.append(frame)
        nframes += 1
        try:
            frame.seek( nframes )
        except EOFError:
            break;
    return frames, nframes

frames, nframes = extractFrames('1.gif')
interval = 100
# In documentation says duration is interval time, but it is total time.
total_duration = nframes*interval
# Save into a GIF file that loops forever
frames[0].save('1_1.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=total_duration, loop=0)
```

However the filesize is about 10x of the original image.

I don't understand why is this happening and can this be prevented?

I also tried using Exiftool to only change the metadata, but this doesn't work for me either:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -XMP-xmpDM:Duration={Scale="s",Value=14} 1.gif
Warning: Improperly formed structure for XMP-xmpDM:Duration
Warning: Improperly formed structure for XMP-xmpDM:Duration
Nothing to do.
```

Comment: You can change the delay at the command line with **ImageMagick** `convert input.gif -coalesce -set delay 20 result.gif` where `20` means 20 centiseconds, i.e. 20/100 seconds per frame.

Comment: Also with `gifsicle --batch -d 300 animated.gif` That would be FAR smaller an installation than ImageMagick.